# OGNL null value for property

Tags: java, ognl

I have a strange situation working with `ognl-3.1.11.jar` ( upgraded from `3.1.10` where I didn't have this problem).

The values for `cVer` and `pVer` are `null`, although they are sent in the same way as childId and parentId. If I rename the properties childVer and parentVer, everything works fine. What could be the difference between these two versions that causes this behavior ?

Below is My code :

```
public class GenealogyOperation {

private Long childId;
private Long parentId;
private Long cVer;
private Long pVer;

public Long getChildId() {
    return childId;
}

public void setChildId(Long childId) {
    this.childId = childId;
}

public Long getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}

public void setParentId(Long parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

public Long getCVer() {
    return cVer;
}

public void setCVer(Long cVer) {
    this.cVer = cVer;
}

public Long getPVer() {
    return pVer;
}

public void setPVer(Long pVer) {
    this.pVer = pVer;
 }
}
```

Comment: This should not cause any error!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4616

Comment: Thank you, @Aleksander M. The get and set should be getcVer() and setcVer().  (Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone. So for example, “FooBah” becomes “fooBah” “Z” becomes “z” “URL” becomes “URL” )